# Input loses focus in React after one keystroke

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After each keystroke in the textinput and the textarea input they lose focus, its strange to me because I have inputs on my homepage this exact same way and they work fine. I've tried changing the onchange to an arrow function and that stops them from losing focus, but then the functions to change the state never get called.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false,
    };
  }
  setBugTitle = e => {
    this.setState({ BugTitle: e.target.value });
    console.log(this.state.BugTitle);
  };
  setBugDescription = e => {
    this.setState({ BugDescription: e.target.value });
    console.log(this.state.BugDescription);
  };

render() {
const Group = () => {
 <Provider store={store}>
            <div className="App">  
              <div className="flex-container">
                <div className="bugSubmission">
                  <ul id="newBug">
                    <h3>Submit New Bug</h3>
                    <li>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Title..."
                        value={this.state.BugTitle}
                        onChange={this.setBugTitle.bind(this)}
                      ></input>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <textarea
                        placeholder="Enter Description..."
                        value={this.state.BugDescription}
                        onChange={this.setBugDescription.bind(this)}
                      ></textarea>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
    <Provider />
}}
```

Comment: The code is working for me . Also you need not call bind(this) if youre using arrow functions . Just use this.setBugDescription instead of this.setBugDescription.bind(this)

Comment: Lucky.. lol. Still having the issue with this exact code.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-2p74v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark     check this sandbox .

Comment: Is this truly your exact code? I'm not sure if this would even render anything as the `render` method doesn't return anything. It only creates a new component (note, a new _component_) but doesn't render it.

Comment: @cubrr well I do have a Router with a switch at the bottom, where based on the path it renders that component, but anything relevant to the issue is there.